# Distinct generalized eigenspaces have trivial intersection

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, generalized-eigenvector

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space and $T \in \mathrm{End}(V)$. Let $\alpha,\beta$ also be two distint eigenvalues for $T$ and $V_\alpha, V_\beta$ are the generalized eigenspaces relative to them. I want to prove that $V_\alpha \cap V_\beta=\{0\}$.

It is given a hint:

> Take $v \in V_\alpha \cap V_\beta$ and consider the subspace $U$ generated by $\{v,Tv,\dots,T^kv\}$ where $k$ is the maximum number s.t. they are linear indipendent and compute the matrix of $T|_U$ in that basis.

The matrix is

$$
   A= \begin{pmatrix}
    0 & 0 & 0 & \dots & 0 & a_0\\
    1 & 0 & 0 & \dots & 0 & a_1\\
    0 & 1 & 0 & \dots & 0 & a_2\\
    \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots\\
    0 & 0 & 0 & \dots & 0 & a_{k-1}\\
    0 & 0 & 0 & \dots & 1 & a_k
    \end{pmatrix}
$$

where $(a_i)$ are the coordinates of $T^{k+1}v$.

I noticed that $U \subseteq V_\alpha \cap V_\beta$ so exists $n>0$ such that we have $(A-\alpha I)^n=0=(A-\beta I)^n$ (from this condition maybe we can get $\alpha=\beta$ but it gets messy very soon)

Comment: Do you know what a [companion matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix) is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see the utility of computing the matrix of $T|_U$, as is suggested.

I would recommend the following approach.  Show that because $(T|_U - \alpha I)^n = 0$, there can be no vector $u \in U$ for which $u \neq 0$ and $(T|_U - \beta I)u = 0$.  However, $(T|_U - \beta I)^n = 0$. Why does this allow us to conclude that $U = \{0\}$?

---

We are given that $(T|_U - \alpha I)^n = (T|_U - \beta I)^n = 0$. Suppose for the sake of contradiction that $U \neq \{0\}$. Let $u \in U$ be a non-zero vector. There exists a largest $k$ for which $(T|_U - \alpha I)^k u \neq 0$; let $v = (T|_U - \alpha I)^k u$. We see that $v \neq 0$ with $Tv = \alpha v$. It follows that $(T|_U - \beta I)^n v = (\alpha - \beta)^n v \neq 0$, which contradicts our supposition that $(T|_U - \beta I)^n = 0$.

Conclude that $U = \{0\}$.

Comment: If $u \neq 0$, $(T-\beta)u=0$ and $(T-\alpha)^n u=0$ we would have that the vector $v=(T-\alpha)^{n-1}u$ is an eigenvector of eigenvalue $\alpha$ and $\beta$ because $(T-\alpha)^{n-1}$ commutes with $(T-\beta)$. So $\alpha=\beta$ which is a contradiction

Comment: This allow us to conclude that $U=\{0\}$ because we have that $(T-\alpha)^n v=0$ $(v \in V_\alpha)$ so necessarily $(T-\alpha)^{n-1}v=0$ until we get $(T-\alpha)v=0 \implies v=0$ so $U=span(v,Tv,\dots,T^kv)=\{0\}$. Are these arguments both correct?

Comment: I think you have the right general idea but I find your comments a bit too confusing to say whether or not they are correct. I'll add a proof of my own in a bit.

Comment: See my latest edit